# Why does loading base64 content into a iframe src attribute sometimes fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why does the second attempt at loading the script into a empty iframe fail? i understand the first one failing because i am trying to load a script in after the page has loaded, but i would have expected the second and third attempts to work. i thought it could have been a security restriction on the browser but normally you would see a error in the console and replacing the script with something like `<script>alert(1);</script>` works fine.

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/616ntt6f/13/)

## html

```
<iframe id="blah1">
</iframe>

<iframe id="blah2">
</iframe>

<iframe id="blah2-2">
</iframe>

<iframe id="blah3">
</iframe>
```

## javascript

```
(function(){
  var content = '<html><head></head><body>' + '<' + 'scr' + 'ipt src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/81b03hN1-8gn7GBWz.js"><\/'+'scr' + 'ipt'+'>' + '</body></html>';

  //attempt 1
  var $body = $('body', $('#blah1').get(0).contentWindow.document);
  $body.html(content);

  //attempt 2
  $('#blah2').attr('src', "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(content));

  //simple alerts work
  $('#blah2-2').attr('src', "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape('<sc' + 'ript>alert(1);</scr' + 'ipt>'));

  //attempt 3
  var doc = $('#blah3').get(0).contentWindow.document;
  doc.open();
  doc.write(content);
  doc.close();
})();
```

After running this in firefox i see some ssl related errors so maybe it's not working because the base64 iframe is treated as a http window although you see nothing in chrome console about ssl errors so it could be unrelated.

Comment: maybe not related to you question, but why are you doing this: `' + '<' + 'scr' + 'ipt`  ?

Comment: @abimelex jsfiddle complains about script tag being inside the script and i've also found some browsers won't allow you to write out script either for security reasons (although in this case i couldn't check that as js fiddle wouldn't run it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you don't see any ssl errors in chrome because you can't use protocol relative script URL's when using base64 data URI's, weirdly if i use srcdoc to set the iframe content (commented out in the example) the protocol relative script URL works. Once i had worked this out it looks like the ssl errors causes enough problems for the player not to load.

The player scripts do actually handle switching between HTTP and HTTPS however as the check is doing `window.location.href.indexOf("https")` it always thinks you are on HTTP and loads the wrong scripts

```js
(function(){
  var content = '<html><head></head><body>' + 
  '<' + 'scr' + 'ipt>' + `
   console.log(window.location.protocol, window.location.href, window.location.href.indexOf("https"));
  ` + '<\/'+'scr' + 'ipt'+'>' +
  '<' + 'scr' + 'ipt src="https://content.jwplatform.com/players/81b03hN1-8gn7GBWz.js"><\/'+'scr' + 'ipt'+'>' + '</body></html>';

  $('#blah1').attr('src', "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(content));
  //$('#blah1').attr('srcdoc', content);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe id="blah1">
</iframe>
```